# Angular 8 and spring boot api, Required request body is missing

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a little issue. When i send a request to my api with Postman, it works, but when i send something with angular he doesn't like.

Postman : [the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if0Ua.png)

Happy Spring :

```
@GetMapping("/searchs")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public Collection<SearchFeedDTO> getFeed ( @RequestBody String data){
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println("I'm here");
    return null;
}
```

[server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paIIg.png)

Angular code:

```
// data = {test:"hello"};
getFeed(data):Observable<boolean>{

   return this.http.get<Answer>(`${this.baseUrl}api/searchs/`,data).pipe(
        map(res=>true),
        catchError(err=>{
            console.error(err);
            return of (false);
      })
   );
}
```

Sad Spring response : "required request body is missing"

And Angular isnt happy when i'm trying this.

```
return this.http.get<Answer>(`${this.baseUrl}api/searchs/`,{test:"test"}).pipe(
```

=> error "No overload matches this call".

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: HttpClient does not support sending data in GET request. You either need to change the method to POST or send the data in query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient does not support sending body in GET request. Based on @vicb's comment [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9927#issuecomment-231511602):

> IIRC the RFC does not prevent GET request from having a body but in
> practice most servers do not support this.

From GET [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1):

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

So you either need to send the request as POST or send the data as query parameters. For multiple data, you could contain the data in an object and send a stringified version as a query parameter.

```js
const test = {test: "test"};
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}api/searchs/?test=` + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(test));
```

And use the `test` variable in the backend.

Comment: I'm going to try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually Get request should not have `body` so angular httpclient.get also don't accept body,
either you need to send data to `GET` via query parameters

or change your backend to `POST` and then use the body. If your body is only text (not json), also you need to add correct headers to angular request

Answer (score 0):

To complete HTTP request you should implement the subscriber because you are creating the request using Observable.